# In pycharm, how to increase the memory of each py file when it is running?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run the `py file`, I see from the task manager that each `python.exe` only occupies `500M` of memory. How do I increase it?

I modified the memory configuration in `pycharm64.exe.vmoptions`, but this seems to be the memory setting of the IDE, `not` the memory setting of python.

Comment: Why do you need more memory? Python is an adult, if it needs more memory, it just ask for it to OS. In your case, it seems Python doesn't need more memory (for now)

Comment: This may have something to do with Windows rather than PyCharm. On my (Linux) machine, a Python process spawned from PyCharm takes as much memory as needed by the task it tries to accomplish, even if the memory for the IDE itself caps at ~ 1 GB.

Comment: I have seen before that in the settings of pycharm, the maximum memory of python.exe can be set to 2G, but now I can't find where to set it.

Answer (score 0):

The support staff of pycharm responded:

PyCharm doesn't set a memory limit for Python processes and doesn't have any control over them in this regard.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.